# C# UTF-8 Byte position in a String

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, character-encoding, byte

I have a external 3. party library which makes analysis on a string, and returns a list of interesting things/events in the given string.

My problem is the 3. party library returns the found position as a byte position, and not a string position, when I deliver the String to the 3. party I deliver it as a UTF-8 Encodede byte[] using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), so it does make sense it returns as a byte position.

Because a character in UTF-8 does not have a fixed size, I can't directly translate it to a String position.

The problem is:

"**I am your father**" "your" is found at byte position 5 with length 4

"**I am yøur father**" "yøur" is found at byte position 5 with length 5

"**I am your father**" "father" is found at byte position 10 with length 6

"**I am yøur father**" "father" is found at byte position 11 with length 6

My question is, how can I translate a byte position to a String position?

Comment: It is bad... There is no way other than parsing the string... It is O(n) in time.

Comment: very slowly. Iterate over the string codepoint by codepoint (note that non-BMP characters are encoded in two code units/Chars in UTF-16 which .NET uses), count the number of UTF-8 bytes for that character, and for the first character that passes it, that's your string position.

Comment: Why do you need the position in the string? The case might be that its easier to work directly with the byte[] instead of a string further down the codingpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is O(n), so it is bad but:

```
string str = "I am yøur father";
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

int len;
int ix = YourMethod(utf8, out len);

int ix2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(utf8, 0, ix);
int len2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(utf8, ix, len);
```

The `ix2` and `len2` are in .NET `char`s.

Note that you could do a simple optimization:

```
int ix2;
int len2;

if (str.Length != utf8.Length)
{
    ix2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(utf8, 0, ix);
    len2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetCharCount(utf8, ix, len);
}
else
{
    ix2 = ix;
    len2 = len;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get better than `O(N)`

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You can do an optimization: if `utf8.Length == str.Length` then no mapping is necessary.

Comment: @Ralf :-) You are right :-) I was testing it with a method that returned fixed 11 and 5 :-)

Comment: Note that the fancy 3rd party library returns a list of positions, so you'll need to aggregate over it

Comment: I might be missing something fundamental, but why not simply use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8, ix, len);`? Since the byte array being sent in is UTF8 and (hopefully) the processing of it also in UTF8 in the 3rd Party

Comment: @BerndLinde Because he doesn't want a `string`, he wants indexes. Given the indexes and the original string, he can easily `str.Substr(ix2, len2);`. He asked explicitly *My question is, how can I translate a byte position to a String position?*

Comment: Aha, missed that last line below the examples. Cleared up, thanks

Comment: @BerndLinde But yes, if he really only wants a string piece, using that overload is the fastest way.